# Im trying to read a csv file from GCS bucket using spark and writing as delta lake(path in GCS) but not able to do write operation

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform, delta-lake

Im trying in IntelliJ and have added the dependency in `pom.xml` file.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Below are the code used:

```
val df_gcs = spark.read.format("csv").csv(sourcepath )

df_gcs.write.format("delta").save(save_path)
```

Getting Below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/command/LeafRunnableCommand
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
> at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:150)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:409)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)

Comment: Changed the version as <version>1.0.0</version> and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Delta Lake versions should match to specific Spark versions. See the matrix here: https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the version as 1.0.0 and it fixed the issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
        <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```